# propgress bar in notificationbar when app closed from background

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar, kill-process

I am updating progress in notificaton bar in my application
when the app is closed or the task is interupted i want to show the message some thing went wrong How to do that?
(my progressbar is updating when the app is in foreground (not killed).)

Comment: use `Services` and `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Thank you 
i have same thing in my mind
any other alternate solution ?

Comment: I can't think of any other alternate. Services are best to work with in these cases. If you want a good example I can post one.

Comment: Please post the example